# Missing prerequisite for emacs-x11 on SLES 15

Tags: emacs, installation, sles

I'm trying to install the emacs-x11 package on SLES 15 and getting the following error:

> nothing provides libm17n-core.so.0()(64bit) needed by emacs-x11-25.3-3.3.18.x86_64

Has anyone else encountered this error, and more importantly know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using YaST to add the M17N software repository at http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/M17N/SLE_15/ solved my problem.